# Create group numbers for rows from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of 6000 records, first 100 records should be batch-1, 2nd 100 should be batch-2 and so on. Kindly help me with the SQL query for the below 
question.

Below is the example of how I have wanted the data

Input

```
data
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

I want output as

```
data  batch
1     Batch-1
2     Batch-1  
3     Batch-1
4     Batch-1
5     Batch-2
6     Batch-2
7     Batch-2
8     Batch-2
9     Batch-3
10    Batch-3
11    Batch-3
12    Batch-3
```

Comment: Is that "data" column consecutive or is it possible that you have gaps in that column (e.e. `1,2,4,7,10,11`) ?

Comment: the data column is consecutive

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to get batches of 100 items:

```
SELECT t.*,
       'Batch-' || CEIL( ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY data ) / 100 ) AS batch
FROM   table_name t;
```

or, if `data` is consecutive then:

```
SELECT t.*,
       'Batch-' || CEIL( data / 100 ) AS batch
FROM   table_name t;
```